# Cannot create a table in H2 with a custom enum

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2, jpa-2.0

We have an entity, let's call it Test.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST", schema = "KAA")
public class Test implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "uuid", unique = true)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "blah", columnDefinition = "enum??")
    private Blah blah = Blah.A;

//..etc

}
```

The type Blah is an enum that looks like this :

```
public enum Blah {

    A("A"),
    B("B");

    private final String name;

    private Blah(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

How is it possible to persist the enum type in the H2 database? The H2 database cannot intiailise the table with this enum type.

In my spring boot configuration I have this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS KAA
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Apparantly you can override the INIT in the config.

INIT=CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS enum as VARCHAR(255);

As I already have an INIT in my config, appending this INIT does not seem to work.

If I append like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS KAA;INIT=CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS enum as VARCHAR(255)
```

It says that the INIT is doubled.

If I comma seperate it :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS KAA,INIT=CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS enum as VARCHAR(255)
```

It says there is a syntax error.

Does anyone know how to write the INIT properly, and more generally, how to go about enums in a H2 database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation on the `blah` field? No `columnDefinition` or other stuff should be necessary... If you really want H2 to use the enum type, you can create the column with the [enum data type](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#enum_type) which would be `columnDefintion="ENUM('A', 'B')"`...